# MySqlException was unhandled on the adapter.Fill(table) when trying to add data to the datagrid

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

When my SQL query has a count function in the query it does not want to display the data in the DBGRID and I'm getting a "MySqlException was unhandled" error. As soon as I remove the count function it runs smoothly and displays the data on the DB grid.

Code below:

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(a.client_id), a.CLIENT_ID,b.c_name, b.C_surname FROM tblinv_info a JOIN  tblclientinfo b ON a.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID WHERE extract(year from a.inv_date) in ('2018','2019') AND a.Client_id = b.Client_id GROUP BY a.client_id ORDER BY count(a.client_id) desc LIMIT 10", connection)

cmd.CommandTimeout = 500

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

Dim table As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(table)

dbreport.DataSource = table
```

Any idea on why this could be happening? I'm running the program in Visual Studio coding with VB.NET and using a MySql database. The SQL command runs fine on the localhost database. Do I need to add data to the datagrid differently?

Error: Error code is as follows: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump out at me as being potentially wrong here:

- You need to give your count column an alias
- If you're running your MySQL in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode (you probably aren't, as you assert it works without the count, but you should), then you need to add `b.c_name, b.C_surname` to your `GROUP BY` or put them in aggregation functions (e.g. `MAX(b.c_name) as c_name, MAX(b.C_surname) as c_surname`) in your SELECT

On this latter point, if you don't group or aggregate and your MySQL is not in "only full groupby", then it will select values at random from the group, for c_name and c_surname, and this can lead to unexpected program effects

As a final point of advice, always avoid using functions on columns in the where clause. It would be better to say `WHERE somedate >= '2018-01-01' AND somedate < 2020-01-01'` than `WHERE extract(YEAR from somedate) IN (2018,2019)`. If you use a function on a column value MySQL has to evaluate the function for every row, and it means indexes on the column cannot be used.

Comment: Only issue I have is when i remove the COUNT(a.client_id), from my SQL query everything works fine . As soon as i Add the COUNT(a.client_id) On the select statement then the error occurs

Comment: I also updated my SQL query and with the same issue i believe it has something to do with the Count function in the select statement.